# Sublime3 text can't ignore PEP8 formatting for Python

Tags: python, sublimetext, pep8

I installed Sublime for Python programming but I found that PEP8 error detection is pretty annoying and I couldn't get rid of it.

I tried this but it's not working:

[image]

It kept showing this:

[image]

Comment: Note: Python expands tabs to every 8th position; if you mix tabs and spaces you'll find that your editor and Python are going to disagree on what is indented to what level when you set it to 4 instead. Using tabs is strongly recommended against.

Comment: I still don't understand why tab is recommended against? I thought tab is forced in python.

Comment: No, *indentation* is required. You can indent with either spaces or tabs. However, tabs are easily confused for spaces and vice versa, people often don't understand how tabs are expanded to the next nth position (they are not a fixed size), and there is no standard tab size across editors (though most settle for 4 or 8), which is why the PEP8 style-guide tells you to use spaces.

Comment: Sublime, like most code editors, can be configured to insert spaces whenever you use the TAB key to indent by setting the `"translate_tabs_to_spaces"` configuration option to `true`, or using the `View -> Indentation -> Indent Using Spaces` menu option.

Comment: Yeah, I changed 'translate_tabs_to_spaces' and it works now. Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `"pep8": false,`.

If it does not work,  add `"sublimelinter_disable":["python"],` to disable python's inspections completely.

And you would like to look https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-pep8